# I can not install Netcdf Library

Tags: 16.04

How can I install netcdf Library, I tried this that exists here
[compiling WRF](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php)

but whitout result, because when i write : which netcdf , I do not get any message

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried via `apt`? When I search for `netcdf` with:

```
apt search netcdf
```

I get  an entry called: `netcdf-bin/xenial 1:4.4.0-2 amd64`

Comment: yes, but how can I know that I have netcdf or not ?

Comment: Find if a package is installed  :  `ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep netcdf` ... And  `dpkg -s [package name]` ... Install netcdf : `sudo apt install libnetcdf-dev`